# How to fix Allowed memory size exhausted in Laravel Swiftmailer?

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer

Hello so i have this problem.
I updated my Laravelproject from 5.4 to 5.7.
After i wasnt able to send Mails anymore. I made sure i have the correct Swiftmailer package and all Versions. 
After some research i found, that my Application is crashing at Mailer.php in the function addContent().

```
protected function addContent($message, $view, $plain, $raw, $data)
    {
        if (isset($view)) {
            /* At this Point my application is crashing.
            $message->setBody($this->renderView($view, $data), 'text/html');
            */
        }

        if (isset($plain)) {
            $method = isset($view) ? 'addPart' : 'setBody';

            $message->$method($this->renderView($plain, $data), 'text/plain');
        }

        if (isset($raw)) {
            $method = (isset($view) || isset($plain)) ? 'addPart' : 'setBody';

            $message->$method($raw, 'text/plain');
        }
    }
```

My php errorlog shows this error message:

```
"PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in C:\\webroot\\projectname\\vendor\\symfony\\debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException.php on line 1, referer: http://localhost/intranet/projectname/other-applications/create"
```

Anyone has some tips how i can fix my problem?

Comment: Start by figuring out whether the problem is actually with Swift Mailer, or with your template that you are trying to render there - if you do just `$foo = $this->renderView($view, $data);` in that place, does it still crash?

Comment: @Cbroe It still crashes if i try this instead 

`if (isset($view)) {
      
            $foo = $this->renderView($view, $data);
            echo "HEre";
            dd($view);
        }`

Answer (score -1):

After some more research i found that it seems like its crashing in my Controller where i build the message.

This is my Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\Models\Application;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ApplicationCreated extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $isForSecretary;
    public $isForHeadPhysician;
    public $isForManagement;

    public $application;
    public $customMsg;

    /**
     * ApplicationCreated constructor.
     * @param Application $application
     * @param $isForSecretary
     * @param $isForHeadPhysician
     * @param null $customMsg
     */
    public function __construct(Application $application, $isForSecretary, $isForHeadPhysician, $customMsg = null)
    {
        $this->application = $application;
        $this->isForSecretary = $isForSecretary;
        $this->isForHeadPhysician = $isForHeadPhysician;
        $this->customMsg = $customMsg;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {

        $applicant = $this->application->applicant;

        return $this->view('application.responses.emails.application_created')
            ->subject('Reiseantrag: ' . $applicant->title . ' ' . $applicant->lastname)
            ->withApplication($this->application)
            ->withMail($this)
            ->with('customMsg', $this->customMsg);
    }
}
```

In the build-function it seems like its crashing somewhere in the return statement.